TypeScript to JavaScript (browser-only target) transpiler that doesn't depend on Node.JS/NPM
I occasionally need to write a small amount of browser-side JavaScript. I would like to use TypeScript instead, because of many of JavaScript's quirks, especially in relation to its dynamic typing. I never write server-side code in JavaScript/TypeScript.
I am looking for a TypeScript to JavaScript transpiler that targets the browser, and does not require a Node.JS environment, or the NPM package manager, to run on my local system. Preferably it should be a small compiled program written in C/Go/Rust. It must be Free Software.
